# Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am testing my Web API. Mocking the data I have this:

```
string json = "{
    "PrintId": 10,
    "Header": "header",
    "TC": "tc",
    "CompanyRef": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
   }"; 
var objs = ((JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)).Values<JObject>();
```

Which gives me the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'

The thing is it was working. I must have changed something, but I don't know what.

My intent is to convert this JSON object to a list of .NET objects called `Print` which has the fields:

```
PrintId
Header
TX
CompnayRef
```

Comment: The answer is simple. It is not an array. It is an object, and you try to cast it to an array.

Comment: Nothing wrong with *this* code - the json text is *not* an array, it's a dictionary. If you thought it was working before, either the text was different or the cast.

Comment: The code you've provided was definitely *not* working for the same JSON.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev hi, thanks. the thing is I need to parse it as an object.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will be probably deleting this question  in a mo :)

Comment: Then just *don't* cast it. It's already a JObject

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just make a class and deserialize it.

```
public class Print
{
    public int PrintId { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string TC { get; set; }
    public string CompanyRef { get; set; }
}

Print printObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Print>(yourJson);
printObj.PrintId = //...
```

Comment: If say, Print had a sub object that was an arraylist, how would you deserialize that so that the arraylist wasn't still in json format?

Comment: @CBC_NS Just like you would do it now, add the property to the print class (like `public List<Type> PropertyName { get; set; }`) and deserialize it as described.

Comment: @Rinecamo Are you saying deserialize each subobject as you would the parent object; I can't deserialize the parent and child objects all at once?

Comment: @CBC_NS Deserialize the parent object and it will automatically deserialize the sub objects.

Comment: @Rinecamo I've tried doing that, and it only deserializes the parent.  I have had to loop through the sub objects and deserialize them one by one, and then loop through each sub objects sub objects. =/  Is there a setting you have to pass in to achieve this?

Comment: @CBC_NS Then I guess you are doing it the wrong way, wanna provide some code?

Answer (score 12):

As the message says, your object is `JObject` so don't cast it to `JArray`. Try this:

```
var objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ \"PrintId\":10,\"Header\":\"header\",\"TC\":\"tc\",\"CompanyRef\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"}");
```

**Update** To get a collection `List<Print>`, your JSON needs to be an array. Try this (I made your JSON an array and added a second object):

```
string json = "[{ \"PrintId\":10,\"Header\":\"header\",\"TC\":\"tc\",\"CompanyRef\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"}"
            + ",{ \"PrintId\":20,\"Header\":\"header2\",\"TC\":\"tc2\",\"CompanyRef\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"}]";
var objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Print>>(json);

//The loop is only for testing. Replace it with your code.
foreach(Print p in objs){
    Console.WriteLine("PrintId: " + p.PrintId);
    Console.WriteLine("Header: " + p.Header);
    Console.WriteLine("TC: " + p.TC);
    Console.WriteLine("CompanyRef: " + p.CompanyRef);
    Console.WriteLine("==============================");
}

public class Print
{
    public int PrintId { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string TC { get; set; }
    public string CompanyRef { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yuJr1T).

Comment: It's *already a JObject*, that's what the error message is talking about

Comment: Yes, I forgot to delete it at the end of the line. Try it now.

Comment: Hi, it does not error this time but how do i get it into my List<Print> collection?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson the answerer posted this before your edit. In the future, be sure to explain what your *actual* problem is, not the problem with your attempted solution. If you had, everyone would have answered that Json.NET can parse Json to strongly-typed objects. There's even a name for such kinds of questions, [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: To get a collection `List<Print>`, your JSON needs to be an array. Check my update.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi, you were right (re: other question). It was my rubbish code.  Issue was with async Thread structures.. apologies

Answer (score 3):

Simply because { } is a jobject notation, to make it a jarray just put square brackets around it e.g. [{ }]. So in your case, just putting these two chars fixes the problem.

```
var objs = ((JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("[{ \"PrintId\":10,\"Header\":\"header\",\"TC\":\"tc\",\"CompanyRef\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"}]")).Values<JObject>();
```

you can try here
https://dotnetfiddle.net/RmgGw8

Note: You said it was working before. So this string input probably is a result of a serialization. You did not have a problem before, because your input was always an array with multiple items until this one. And your serializer is probably producing a single object (output starting with '{') instead of an array (output starting with '[') for single item arrays.

[serializing List with single object as JSON object not JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608668/serializing-list-with-single-object-as-json-object-not-json-array)

Answer (score 1):

For me I was putting empty string as an object which caused the issue, I switched to "{}" which fixed my issue

Comment: Need to define like this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363139/error-when-deserializing-json-to-object