# Getting error Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'

Tags: c#

```
JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(response);
JObject ojObject = (JObject)joResponse["d"];
JArray userResponseArray = (JArray)ojObject["results"];
foreach(JArray ja in userResponseArray)
{
----
}
```

I am getting above error for foreach line

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp - 90% of your JSON parsing problems gone via auto-generation to safety!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495634/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-newtonsoft-json-linq-jobject-to-type-newtonsoft).

Comment: @mjwills Could also use `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes` in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yep, not quite as nice (in terms of casing etc) but that does also work @RoadRunner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JArray` is containting an array of `JObject` in this case so you have `JObject` collection in the JArray your loop should look like:

```
foreach(JObject ja in userResponseArray)
{
   string yourKey = item.GetValue("yourKey").ToString();
}
```

Comment: `JArray` is an array of `JToken` see [the docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) and it can contain anything like `JArray`, `JObject`, `JValue`, ...

Comment: @SirRufo yes but in this case it is containing an array of  `JObject`, i edited the post, Thanks for the correction